# Is it possible to fit separate parts of an sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, model-fitting

Consider having following sklearn `Pipeline`:

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    TfidfVectorizer(),
    LinearRegression()
)
```

I have `TfidfVectorizer` pretrained, so when I am calling `pipeline.fit(X, y)` I want only `LinearRegression` to be fitted and I don't want to refit `TfidfVectorizer`.

I am able to just apply transformation in advance and fit `LinearRegression` on transformed data, but in my project I have a lot of transformers in a pipeline, where some of them are pretrained and some aren't, so I am searching for a way of not writing another wrapper around sklearn estimators and stay in a bounds of one `Pipeline` object.

To my mind, it should be a parameter in the estimators object that stands for not refitting object when calling `.fit()` if object is already fitted.

Answer (score 3):

Look at "memory" parameter. It caches transformers from a pipeline.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    TfidfVectorizer(),
    LinearRegression(),
    memory='cache_directory'
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it is not what I am trying to accomplish. According to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#caching-transformers-avoid-repeated-computation, cache is used when parameters and input data are identical to those on what it was fit. But in my case, I want to fit `LinearRegression` on **new data**, while `TfidfVectorizer` was fit on another data and stays same.

The whole point is I want to train transformer once, and use it later in a pipelines on a new data without refitting transformer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find only the regressor by defining your pipeline as follows:

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(steps = [
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer()),
    ('regressor', LinearRegression())
])
```

and then

```
pipeline['regressor']
```

should give you only the regressor.

Comment: But suppose you have a lot of estimators inside pipeline, calling each of them separately is not very convenient.
Also, if you want to optimize pipeline using `GridSearchCV`, you are not able to call each estimator's fit separately.

Comment: Try [Voting Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) if you need separate result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hack to fit transformer only once

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def fit_once(transformer):
    fitted = [False]

    def func(x):
        if not fitted[0]:
            transformer.fit(x)
            fitted[0] = True
        return transformer.transform(x)

    return FunctionTransformer(func)

pipeline = make_pipeline(
    fit_once(TfidfVectorizer()),
    LinearRegression()
)
```